# Please help me in counting the number of days I was outside de United States, to write the right answer on the N-400

Tags: usa, citizenship

Since I got my green card, I've traveled 3 times as follow:

First trip
Country: Chile
Departure day from the US: 01/16/2019 (evening)
Arriving back to the US: 04/15/2019 (morning)

Second trip
Country: Chile
Departure day from the US: 07/25/2022 (evening)
Arriving back to the US: 09/21/2022 (morning)

Third trip
Country: Mexico
Departure day from the US: 11/12/2022 (morning)
Arriving back to the US: 11/20/2022 (afternoon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How am I supposed to count the days on the N400? Eg if I left the US at 3 PM PT and came back the next day at 4 PM PT, does that count as 1 or 2 days?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/how-am-i-supposed-to-count-the-days-on-the-n400-eg-if-i-left-the-us-at-3-pm-pt)

Comment: 88 days, 57 days, 7 days.  152 days.